# Weird green and blue lines after login on 17 inch macbook pro high sierra

Tags: display

I have a 17" macbook pro late 2011 on macos high sierra and once i log in there is weird green and blue lines on the screen going sideways. Please help when i plus in a external monitor these lines still appear. I have tried reseting the pram and smc and that still does not fix it.

Comment: can you make a photo and upload it please?

Comment: I can't really  use the mouse with the weird lines